# My page loads fine on pc or Mac but totally disappears on iPad or iPhone with iOS 5.1.1

Tags: iphone, python, html, ios, ipad

After upgrading to ios 5.1.1 from 4.2.1, my page www.zolkan.com loads and immediately disappears showing a blank gray page. I did not change anything on my page for over a year.
Before upgrading my iPhone from 4.2.1 to 5.1.1, it loaded fine. Same was with my iPad running 5.0.1... After going to 5.1.1, the page loads and disappears.

It seems that only the dynamic page (generated by python CGI) is doing this... The rest of the static pages behave normally.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use safari under developer mode as an iOS device to determine the root cause. After looking at what is happening, I bet your social loading code has changed something remotely, specifically, the fb-root tag that is warned about in the error console. Start there by disabling the social network stuff and start debugging.

update: I just disabled javascript on my phone and got the page up so it is definitely a JS bug somewhere.

Comment: You were right on. It was the add-this button that caused it. Facebook's div did raise an error but was no the cause to the disappearing page.